# Codeigniter checkbox array

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

My checkboxes look like this

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="apple" <?php echo set_checkbox('fruits[]', 'apple'); ?> />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="banana" <?php echo set_checkbox('fruits[]', 'banana'); ?> />
    <input type="checkbox" name="fruits[]" value="peach" <?php echo set_checkbox('fruits[]', 'peach'); ?> />
</div>
```

I am using array in the names so that I can populate a text field (via jquery) with the values of the checkboxes I select. I am using a script found on stackoverflow.

```
function calculate() {

        var fruit = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), function(e, i) {
            return e.value;
        });

        $('#fruits').val(fruit.join(',')); //adds values separated by comma to #fruits input 
    }

    calculate();

    $('div').delegate('input:checkbox', 'click', calculate);
```

So far it works but I'm having trouble setting validation rules for the checkboxes because they all have the same name. I tried..

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fruits[]', 'Apple', 'required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fruits[]', 'Banana', 'required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fruits[]', 'Peach', 'required|xss_clean');
```

and used `echo form_error('fruits[]');` to display validation error but nothing happens. Ultimately I want to display a checkbox in the state it was submitted, should an error occur on another field in my form. Instead all the checkboxes uncheck. I'm not sure how to fix this.

POST

```
Array ( [FRUITS] => Array ( [0] => apple [1] => banana [2] => peach )
```

this is when they are checked

Comment: Can you give us your POST? Place this before form validation print_r($_POST); die();

Comment: yes, have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without using the square brackets [], so just 'fruits'.

The [] are just to say to the browser "post these values as an array, not a single value, because they're a group", but in PHP you would just approach it as any other value, viz. $_POST['fruits'].

Hope that helps,

All the best,
NwN

Comment: To clarify, keep the brackets in the HTML, but loose them in:
$this->form_validation->set_rules('fruits', 'Apple', 'required|xss_clean');

Comment: thanks! but without the brackets it doesn't work. I eventually added a loop.

Comment: actually the jquery seems to work with any name as long as its a checkbox. You may be right